# what is the purpose of getEventType() method in XMLStreamReader Class

Tags: java, xml

I have sample code written for parsing xml file using `javax.xml`  package. it uses the method called `getEventType()` , but I can not understand the purpose of this method.

i wrote simple application to understand its usefulness, but it output only some random numbers for which I can not make any sense, could some one help me to get this point right.

Here is the sample code I have written.

```
public List parseXML(File f) throws XMLStreamException{
  xmlInputFactory = new WstxInputFactory();

  xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, Boolean.FALSE);
  xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
  xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.IS_COALESCING,Boolean.FALSE);
  xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.IS_VALIDATING,Boolean.FALSE);
  xmlInputFactory.configureForSpeed();

  List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

  //xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(dmml));
  xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(f);

  int eventType = xmlStreamReader.getEventType();
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  eventType = xmlStreamReader.next();
  System.out.println(eventType);
  /*String currentElement = "";
  String currentElementText = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event types tell you what sort of entity the parser is currently pointed at, for example is it a element start tag, and end tag, an attribute, and so on.

The event types are defined in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html). They're all defined as `int`, so you need to use the table in the javadoc to understand what they mean. The actual numeric values are listed in [XMLStreamConstants](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.html). However, the numeric values are not interesting in themselves, you should use the `XMLStreamConstants`-defined constants by name.

Comment: Thank you skaffman for the answer. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html . This doc does not say for which each integer value is assigned, could you tell me where are these values are defined.

Answer (score 1):

it tells you the index of current object of the xml